# How to access locale in custom app on server-side in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, react-intl

I'm migrating a project from **next.js** 7 to 10. It uses **react-intl** for translations and was written in TypeScript.


In the previous version I **had a custom server.js** and handled **sub-routing** (/de, /fr, etc.) for multilingual purposes **in it**. And in custom app component, through the getInitialProps, I was getting **locale** from **req** and passed it as a prop to my component. So the whole picture was something like this:

Custom app:

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    const { req } = ctx;
    const { locale, messages } = req || (window as any).__NEXT_DATA__.props;
    const initialNow = Date.now();

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }
    return { pageProps, locale, messages, initialNow }
}
```

And the component

```
render() {
        const { Component, pageProps, locale, messages, initialNow } = (this.props as any);
        return (
            <Container>
                <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages} initialNow={initialNow}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </IntlProvider>
            </Container>
        )
    }
```

Now since I'm using next.js 10, for many reasons I removed the custom server.js and did the sub-routing through i18n, so I added this in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   i18n: {
        locales: ["en", "de", "fr"],
        defaultLocale: "en",
    },
}
```

The only thing is that I need to pass the locale to IntlProvider of react-intl in server-side and for all the pages. So I suppose I should do it in custom app and **getInitialProps returns a wrong value for locale (always default)**. And we can't use getServerSideProps  or getStaticProps in custom _app.

So finally! the question is:
How can I access the locale on server-side in one place for all of my pages? Or is there a better approach to solve this issue?

(I can't remove intl and work fully with i18n for now, it needs so much time for this particular project and we don't have it atm!)

Comment: hi, just want to ask the reason you remove your custom server is because next internationalize routing is not support custom server ? @Ali Afsah

Comment: Hi @Anymore, I removed custom server since I wanted to deploy my app on Vercel, plus it made some performance issues. Based on Next.js 10 docs, it's recommended to not using it, unless the default routing system is not enough for your specific tasks. Please take a look at a couple of first lines of this official doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the `locale` in your custom app's `getInitialProps` through the `router` prop.

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx, router }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    const { req } = ctx;
    const { locale } = router; // Will return `fr` for `/fr/*` pages
    const { messages } = req || (window as any).__NEXT_DATA__.props;
    const initialNow = Date.now();

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }
    return { pageProps, locale, messages, initialNow }
}
```

---

When using `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`, outside custom app pages, the active locale can be accessed directly from the context object.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
    console.log(locale) // Logs current locale    
    // ...
}
```

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
    console.log(locale) // Logs current locale    
    // ...
}
```

---

For more details check [Next.js i18n routing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#accessing-the-locale-information) .

Answer (score 4):

for anybody else who's using Next js 13 with the app directory, we can grab the locale as follows:

```js
import { getLocale } from "next-intl/server";

export default function Home() {
  const locale = getLocale();
  console.log("inside server", locale);
  return (
    <main>
      <div>{locale}</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: what about with `page` routing next 12 ? Is there a way to access the `express` request globally from some file and get locale

Comment: Is it possible to use it without `async/await`?