# How to access current language in getStaticProps Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I'm using i18n in my next app, I need to access the current page language in getStaticProps then i fetch data

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  //need to get language here

  return {
    props: { data },
  };
};

const App = ({ data }) => {
  //my component where i can get language

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const currentLang = i18n.language;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js 10 + sub-routing, how to access locale in custom app on server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65438136/1870780)?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the local from the object that is passed to the getStaticProps.
You can see it in this example [from Vercel](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#limits-for-the-i18n-config)

In you case it could look like this:

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  doSomethingWithLocale(locale)

  return {
    props: { data },
  };
};
```